# C program to count lines and words in a file gives wrong word output

Tags: c, word-count, line-count

I created this program to count words and lines but when I input a file that has just a `\n` it says there is one word which is not what I want. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() 
{
    FILE *file; 
    char word[1000];        
    int c;
    int NumLines = 0; 
    int NumWords = 0;
    int was_space = 1;        

    printf("Enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", word);
    file = fopen(word, "r");
    while ((c=fgetc(file)) !=EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            NumLines++;
            if (was_space == 0) {
                NumWords++;
                was_space = 1;
            }
            was_space = 1;
        }
        else if ((c == '\t' || c == '-' || c == ':' || c== ' ') && was_space == 0) {
            NumWords++;
            was_space = 1;
        }
        else if (c != '\n' && c != '\t' && c != '-' && c != ':' && c != ' ') {
           was_space = 0;
           continue;
        }
        else if (was_space == 1)
           continue;
    }
    printf("%d %9d\n", NumLines, NumWords);
    fclose(file);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there aren't two `\n`'s in the file?

Comment: What does your debugging tell you?

Comment: A general tip for debugging: make sure what the program is getting and what you think it's getting is the same. A simple printf("%c", c); at the top of your loop will show you what your program is getting as input.

Comment: In the second `else if`, you know `ch` cannot be `'\n'`.  You should error check the return value from `fopen()`; people misspell file names routinely.

Comment: Include a count of the number of `char` read and print that.  `while ((c=fgetc(file)) !=EOF) { count++;`  Suspect that will be > 1.

Comment: Possible a `'\r'` is lurking someplace.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a program that outputs only a single '\n' character.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { printf("\n"); return 0; }
```

I ran your code on a file that only contained a single '\n' and it output:

```
john-schultzs-macbook-pro:~ jschultz$ ./output_newline > input.txt
john-schultzs-macbook-pro:~ jschultz$ wc input.txt
       1       0       1 input.txt
john-schultzs-macbook-pro:~ jschultz$ cat input.txt

john-schultzs-macbook-pro:~ jschultz$ ./a.out
Enter file name: input.txt
1         0
```

It seems that your test input file actually contains more characters than you think.  On Windows platforms, it is common for lines of text to be terminated by the character sequence "\r\n" rather than only "\n".  On that kind of input, your program prints:

```
john-schultzs-macbook-pro:~ jschultz$ ./a.out
Enter file name: input.txt
1         1
```